# Prolog, comparing dates to see before a given date

Tags: prolog

So in my code on prolog I have facts like the one formatted below:

fish(type, size, date_caught).

I want to create a rule that will allow me to see what fish have been caught before a certain date. So if I type caught_before(2013-12-07). It will show all the fish caught before that date.

Comment: So where exactly is the problem? At what point does your current program fail to deliver the answer you are looking for?

Comment: I dont know how to make a rule which allows me to type in a date that will show all the fish caught before that specific date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the @< operator:

```
1 ?- [user].
|: fish(a,b,2003-10-10).
|: fish(a,b,2003-10-10).
|: fish(a,b,2004-10-10).
|: caught_before(D) :- fish(T,S,D1), D1 @< D.
Warning: user://2:23:
    Singleton variables: [T,S]
|: 
% user://2 compiled 0.02 sec, 2 clauses
true.

2 ?- caught_before(2005-X-Y).
true ;
true ;
true.

2 ?- caught_before(2004-X-Y).
true ;
true ;
false.

2 ?- caught_before(2003-X-Y).
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help :

```
? Y-M-D = 2013-12-08.
Y = 2013,
M = 12,
D = 8.
```

Comment: Hello, I may have not been clear. I need help on creating a rule which allows me to type in a date that will show all the fish caught before that specific date